# ReactJs creating global, reusable components

Tags: reactjs

New to React and trying to wrap my head around how to create and use global components.

For example, I want to create a Modal component that can be triggered on any page (which are pulled into the parent App component with {this.props.children}).

So I've created a Modal Component:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if(this.props.isOpen){
                return (
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                        <div className="modal">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                );
        } else {
                return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300} />;
        }
    }
}
```

And within the main App Component I can open/close the Modal as such:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isModalOpen: false
        }
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    }
    openModal() {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: true
        });
    }
    closeModal() {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: false
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <HeaderContainer />

                <p onClick={this.openModal}>Open modal</p>              
                <Modal transitionName="modal-anim" isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}>
                    <p onClick={this.closeModal}>Close modal</p>
                </Modal>

                <div className="main-content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Also within the App component render {this.props.children} is pulling different pages (as set by the router). Now, from one of these pages -- how would I be able to trigger the Modal and set state on the parent App?

```
<Provider store={store}>
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />;
    <Route path="/features" component={FeaturesList} />
    <Route path="/magazine" component={Magazine} />
  </Route>
</Router>
</Provider>
, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

Specifically, how would I be able to call openModal/closeModal and pass data to the Modal component from the Magazine or FeaturesList components?

Appreciation for any tips/advice, just getting my head into React and have a lot to learn. Thx!

Comment: It looks like you're already using Redux. Have you considered having the modal state be represented as a property in the global Redux state?

Comment: Thanks I'm going to look into this approach, intuitively it makes sense -- just want to make sure I'm adhering to best practices though with creating reusable components.